# When I write {{bookings|json}} it displays me the array of objects. But when I am writing only {{bookings}} it displays me nothing

Tags: node.js, angular, interpolation

#### view.comp.ts

**In view.comp.ts when viewAllBookings() is called, this.flightDetails will get assigned with** 
[{"_id":"5ec8d981fe559619a0a36ab3","flightId":"IND-101","AircraftName":"Delta Airlines","fare":600,"availableSeats":9,"status":"Running","bookings":[{"_id":"5ec8d981fe559619a0a36ab4","customerId":"P1001","bookingId":2001,"noOfTickets":3,"bookingCost":1800},{"_id":"5ec8d981fe559619a0a36ab5","customerId":"S1001","bookingId":2003,"noOfTickets":2,"bookingCost":1200},{"_id":"5ed923926cb1ea3f80f090ef","customerId":"G1001","bookingId":2007,"noOfTickets":1,"bookingCost":600}],"__v":0},{"_id":"5ec8d981fe559619a0a36ab6","flightId":"IND-102","AircraftName":"JetBlue","fare":750,"availableSeats":18,"status":"Running","bookings":[{"_id":"5ec8d981fe559619a0a36ab7","customerId":"P1001","bookingId":2002,"noOfTickets":3,"bookingCost":2250},{"_id":"5ec8d981fe559619a0a36ab8","customerId":"G1001","bookingId":2004,"noOfTickets":2,"bookingCost":1500},{"_id":"5ed924ea6cb1ea3f80f090f0","customerId":"S1001","bookingId":2008,"noOfTickets":2,"bookingCost":1500}],"__v":0},{"_id":"5ec8d981fe559619a0a36ab9","flightId":"IND-103","AircraftName":"United Airlines","fare":800,"availableSeats":10,"status":"Cancelled","bookings":[{"_id":"5ec8d981fe559619a0a36aba","customerId":"S1001","bookingId":2005,"noOfTickets":1,"bookingCost":800},{"_id":"5ec8d981fe559619a0a36abb","customerId":"G1001","bookingId":2006,"noOfTickets":4,"bookingCost":3200}],"__v":0}]

**& this.bookings will get assigned with array of bookings object**  
[ { "_id": "5ec8d981fe559619a0a36ab4", "customerId": "P1001", "bookingId": 2001, "noOfTickets": 3, "bookingCost": 1800, "flightId": "IND-101" }, { "_id": "5ec8d981fe559619a0a36ab5", "customerId": "S1001", "bookingId": 2003, "noOfTickets": 2, "bookingCost": 1200, "flightId": "IND-101" }, { "_id": "5ed923926cb1ea3f80f090ef", "customerId": "G1001", "bookingId": 2007, "noOfTickets": 1, "bookingCost": 600, "flightId": "IND-101" }, { "_id": "5ec8d981fe559619a0a36ab7", "customerId": "P1001", "bookingId": 2002, "noOfTickets": 3, "bookingCost": 2250, "flightId": "IND-102" }, { "_id": "5ec8d981fe559619a0a36ab8", "customerId": "G1001", "bookingId": 2004, "noOfTickets": 2, "bookingCost": 1500, "flightId": "IND-102" }, { "_id": "5ed924ea6cb1ea3f80f090f0", "customerId": "S1001", "bookingId": 2008, "noOfTickets": 2, "bookingCost": 1500, "flightId": "IND-102" }, { "_id": "5ec8d981fe559619a0a36aba", "customerId": "S1001", "bookingId": 2005, "noOfTickets": 1, "bookingCost": 800, "flightId": "IND-103" }, { "_id": "5ec8d981fe559619a0a36abb", "customerId": "G1001", "bookingId": 2006, "noOfTickets": 4, "bookingCost": 3200, "flightId": "IND-103" } ]

```
export class ViewDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

  bookings: Flights[] = []
  flightDetails: FlightBooking[];

 constructor(private viewdetailsservice: ViewDetailsService) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.viewAllBookings()
  }


 viewAllBookings() {
    this.viewdetailsservice.view().subscribe(
      (success)=>{this.flightDetails=success
      this.flightDetails.forEach((ele)=>{
        ele.bookings.forEach((booking)=>{
          booking.flightId=ele.flightId
          this.bookings.push(booking)
        })
      })},
      (error)=>{this.errorMessage=error}
    ) 
 }
}
```

**view.comp.html**

*when i write {{bookings|json}}, it displays me the*
[ { "_id": "5ec8d981fe559619a0a36ab4", "customerId": "P1001", "bookingId": 2001, "noOfTickets": 3, "bookingCost": 1800, "flightId": "IND-101" }, { "_id": "5ec8d981fe559619a0a36ab5", "customerId": "S1001", "bookingId": 2003, "noOfTickets": 2, "bookingCost": 1200, "flightId": "IND-101" }, { "_id": "5ed923926cb1ea3f80f090ef", "customerId": "G1001", "bookingId": 2007, "noOfTickets": 1, "bookingCost": 600, "flightId": "IND-101" }, { "_id": "5ec8d981fe559619a0a36ab7", "customerId": "P1001", "bookingId": 2002, "noOfTickets": 3, "bookingCost": 2250, "flightId": "IND-102" }, { "_id": "5ec8d981fe559619a0a36ab8", "customerId": "G1001", "bookingId": 2004, "noOfTickets": 2, "bookingCost": 1500, "flightId": "IND-102" }, { "_id": "5ed924ea6cb1ea3f80f090f0", "customerId": "S1001", "bookingId": 2008, "noOfTickets": 2, "bookingCost": 1500, "flightId": "IND-102" }, { "_id": "5ec8d981fe559619a0a36aba", "customerId": "S1001", "bookingId": 2005, "noOfTickets": 1, "bookingCost": 800, "flightId": "IND-103" }, { "_id": "5ec8d981fe559619a0a36abb", "customerId": "G1001", "bookingId": 2006, "noOfTickets": 4, "bookingCost": 3200, "flightId": "IND-103" } ]

*but when I write {{bookings}} only then it displays nothing*
*Now my question is when I write {{bookings}} then why not it is showing me [object Object ...] like this*

Comment: can you add a stacblitz?

Comment: Hi, i nam not sure view template display  [object Object]. [object Object] is displayed by the console.
The question is: Why do you want to display  [object Object] ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any use of displaying the array in the view. Most likely the Angular team just didn't care about this case and made some simple implementation which doesn't break anything